# Linking libraries (C++)

Tags: c++, linker

Using MinGW through Eclipse for C/C++, and attempting to get GLUT (OpenGL Utility Toolkit) working on it, but I suspect it's a simple problem.

Attempts to build result in:

g++ -LC:\Documents and Settings\C\workspace\GLUTtest\Debug -LC:\Tools\MinGW\include\GL -LC:\Tools\MinGW\include -oGLUTtest.exe main.o -lglut32.lib
C:\Tools\MinGW\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5........\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: cannot find -lglut32.lib

I have glut32.lib in the workspace directory, C:\Documents and Settings\C\workspace\GLUTtest. Here are the options as given by eclipse:

-L"C:\Documents and Settings\C\workspace\GLUTtest" -L"C:\Documents and Settings\C\workspace\GLUTtest\Debug" -L"C:\Documents and Settings\C\workspace\GLUTtest\GL" -L"C:\Tools\MinGW\include\GL" -L"C:\Tools\MinGW\include"

Any idea why it isn't picking up the library?

Comment: Did you try -lglut32 instead of -lglut32.lib?

Answer (score 1):

Seems your trying to pass include directories as link directories. Find the directory that contains glut32.lib and add a link-directory parameter (-L) with the directory you find.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a library file named libxxx.a, libxxx.so or xxx.lib. When linking, you should put the parameter as -lxxx

And second, sometimes you have to put library path with ( -L/path/to/lib/dir )

Answer (score 0):

Your are passing "C:\Tools\MinGW\include\GL -LC:\Tools\MinGW\include" as your linking directory ( -L ) which seems to be your include path. so pass your include directory in include path which will appear with -I option and just check that whether your linking path is present in the list given with -L options, if not then add it in the list otherwise it will say undefined references.